# Reuse modal dialog with different parent in GTK+ on MS Windows - broken focus

Tags: c, windows, gtk

I'm reusing a modal dialog in GTK+ — I set it's parent dialog using `gtk_window_set_transient_for`, run it, and later reset it's parent to another dialog and run it again.

On Linux everything is fine but on MS Windows the second time this dialog is displayed all GTK windows get confused which one is active.

This is a test program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget* main_window;

void run_reused_dialog(
    GtkWidget* reused_dialog,
    const gchar *parent_title,
    const gchar *reused_dialog_title
) {
    GtkWidget* parent_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
        parent_title,
        GTK_WINDOW(main_window),
        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
        GTK_STOCK_OK,
        GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
        NULL
    );
    gtk_container_add(
        GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(parent_dialog))),
        gtk_label_new(parent_title)
    );
    gtk_widget_show_all(parent_dialog);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(parent_dialog));

    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(reused_dialog),GTK_WINDOW(parent_dialog));
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(reused_dialog), reused_dialog_title);
    GtkWidget* reused_dialog_label = gtk_label_new(GTK_WINDOW(reused_dialog)->title);
    gtk_container_add(
        GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog))),
        reused_dialog_label
    );
    gtk_widget_show_all(reused_dialog);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog));
    gtk_widget_hide(reused_dialog);
    gtk_container_remove(
        GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog))),
        reused_dialog_label
    );
    gtk_widget_hide(parent_dialog);
    gtk_widget_destroy(parent_dialog);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(main_window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);

    /* This is a dialog which will be reused */
    GtkWidget* reused_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
        "Reused dialog",
        GTK_WINDOW(main_window),
        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
        GTK_STOCK_OK,
        GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
        NULL
    );
    gtk_container_add(
        GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog))),
        gtk_label_new(GTK_WINDOW(reused_dialog)->title)
    );

    /* Show first dialog which will display reused dialog */
    run_reused_dialog(
        reused_dialog,
        "First dialog. Click OK to display reused dialog",
        "Reused dialog. Click OK to close"
    );

    /* Show second dialog which will display reused dialog */
    run_reused_dialog(
        reused_dialog,
        "Second dialog. Click OK to display reused dialog",
        "Reused dialog. Switch to another application and switch back"
    );

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

When "Reused dialog. Switch to another application and switch back" dialog is displayed, it ignores mouse, but reacts to keyboard input. Sometimes switching to another application and back triggers this problem.

---

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in Windows GTK port?
2. How to work around it without recreating this dialog every time it is used?
3. Am I allowed to reuse GTK dialogs at all?

---

The sample program source and compiled executable with required GTK libraries is [here](http://prhn.ato.waw.pl/~tometzky/tmp/gtk-reused-dialog.zip). This is cross-compiled using `i686-pc-mingw32-gcc gtk-reused-dialog.c $(mingw32-pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) -mwindows` on Fedora Linux 15 with `mingw32-gtk2` package and it dependencies installed.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. The part that breaks it is the `GTK_DIALOG_MODAL`s; if you remove one of them (in either the *parent* or *reused* dialog) the code works fine. I'm pretty sure it's a GTK+ bug; I don't see anything that should trigger this kind of behaviour. You should probably [report it](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my guess:

1. the problem is related to focus grabbing;
2. the window widget calls grab APIs only when the modal flag [changes its state](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkwindow.c#n2240);
3. differences between platforms are mostly due to implementation details;
4. you cannot have more than a single modal window.

At the time you show `reused_dialog`, it is not clear which dialog is modal (`parent_window` is still alive).

The right solution: I suspect if you refactor your code to show `reused_dialog` from a callback (using the [response](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-response) signal, for example), you'll get the desired result because this is the *usual way™*.

If you don't want to refactor you could try one of these solutions/work-arounds (roughly in order of what I think is better):

- always disactivate the modal state of `reused_dialog` before running it; `gtk_dialog_run()` [will set it](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkdialog.c#n1075%3a) again, triggering what requested:

  ```
  ...
  gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(reused_dialog), FALSE);
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog));
  ...
  ```
- manually grab the focus in `reused_dialog` before running it:

  ```
  ...
  gtk_grab_add(reused_dialog);
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(reused_dialog));
  ...
  ```
- deactivate the modal status of the `parent_window` after run:

  ```
  ...
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(parent_dialog));
  gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(parent_dialog), FALSE);
  ...
  ```